# npm command not working on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed node and npm on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I try to use any npm command, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/cmd-list.js:113
module.exports.aliases = Object.assign({}, shorthands, affordances)
                            ^
TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/cmd-list.js:113:33)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:37:17
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:471:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I'm new to using node and I didn't find any solution to such an error online

Comment: What was an exact command line you tried? Are you using sudo?

Comment: @R.Richards I agree we need the exact command, but i don't think it's related to sudo otherwise it would be EACESS error

Comment: You are right! We would be seeing that in the output. Good catch.

Comment: Im trying to install angular with npm using `npm install angular` command, even with sudo this isnt working. I already tried reinstalling node and npm once.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are most likely running an old version of node.js (verify with `node -v`, at the time of writing this, the latest lts is 6.x). I suppose you tried to install it with `apt-get install nodejs` or similar. The packages shipped with ubuntu 14 are outdated, follow the advice on [nodejs' download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) instead, and do the following:

Step 1, remove the old packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
```

Step 2, type the following commands one after the other and follow the screen:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now you have a version of nodejs installed that allows ES6 methods, as `Object.assign` is one of them

Comment: Is the deb link still valid for today?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Ubuntu **18.04**:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

Answer (score 1):

npm might be older version,

so remove nodejs,

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

then,

```
sudo apt-get install curl #if you dont have curl

Node.js v6:

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Node.js v7:

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Node.js 8:

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

for more info, [package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

### Hi, You can try this one also. This worked for me :)

#optional

sudo apt-get update

#install curl (optional)

sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl

#install  curl node package

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

#Install node

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs