# Unable to update nodejs and npm on Raspbian-Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: node.js, npm, raspbian

My raspbian system is currently running Node.js v4.8.2 and am trying to install its latest version but in vain.I have tried the following solution from this post [npm command not working on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988592/npm-command-not-working-on-ubuntu/44989124) (i.e uninstalling the old packages and installing new ones).When using this command **sudo apt-get install -y nodejs** I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libiw-dev : Depends: libiw30 (= 30~pre9-8) but 30~pre9-12 is to be installed
 nodejs : Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried installing NPM directly using this command: **sudo apt-get install npm**  but I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libiw-dev : Depends: libiw30 (= 30~pre9-8) but 30~pre9-12 is to be installed
 npm : Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: having you tried `apt --fix-broken install`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work.When i use node -v it still show v4.8.2 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
nodejs : Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
```

You should remove all versions of node first.

(Following commands can be referenced at raspberrypi.org's [community page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=141770)):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $  sudo su -
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get remove nodered -y
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy -y
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get remove npm  -y # if you installed npm
```

Make sure you are pointed to correct source.

```
root@raspberrypi:~ # curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo bash -
```

Install, and check versions:

```
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get install nodejs -y
root@raspberrypi:~ # node -v
root@raspberrypi:~ # npm -v
```

Comment: Yeah the problem was with the conflicts. This worked.

Comment: @Elfinforest glad to be of service :)